# Use a variable with special characters as delimiter to explode a string

Tags: php

I have several files that I intend to copy to a db, separating the information throughout several tables. So I need to explode each line to separate the information accordingly.

When I was using just a space separating the information it worked fine, however now I have a lot of files and some of them are seperated by space, semi colon or in some cases a tab. I have the separating character in another table that is read before the inserts begin.

My problem rises when I have a `\t` that needs to be exploded. If I force the explode function, such as:

```
$line = explode("\t", trim($file[$j]));
```

It works just fine. However when I try and use a dynamic way: `$rows['separator']` contains `" "`, `;` or `\t`.

```
$line = explode($rows['separator'], trim($file[$j]));
```

`" "` and `;` work fine, but `\t` doesn't. Can anyone tell me why I can't seem to get this right? Or how I can fix this?

Also I've tried using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function:

```
$line = preg_split($rows['separator'], trim($file[$j]));
```

But only managed to get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Comment: Is the content of $rows['seperator'] equal to '\t', or did you actually store the special character in it? They are not the same thing.

Comment: It is equal to '\t'.

Comment: I believe @Erik is on the right track. Does it work when forcing the variable to "\t"? I.e. `$rows['separator'] = "\t"; $line = explode($rows['separator'], trim($file[$j]));`. Note that the type of quotation marks is important here.

Comment: It does work when I try $line = explode("\t", trim($file[$j])); 
@Typoheads gave an answer with preg_plit that manages to split the string.

Comment: @Comum, `"\t"` will work but `'\t'` won't so the variable should contain `"\t"`.

Comment: So if i change my table from `\t` to `"\t"` it should work with explode() ? I'm goint to try it as well.

Comment: `"\t"` as a value of your array works fine on *php 5*. If you try it out on *php 4* it won't split the string as you expect.

Comment: explode() still won't work, so I'm going to use the preg_split, thanks for the answers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using preg_splt, you should add some slashes to delimit the pattern:

```
$line = preg_split('/' . $rows['separator'] . '/', trim($file[$j]));
```

Comment: preg_split uses a regular expression as first parameter. Regular expressions have to have a character as a delimiter. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is twofold.

`explode($separator, trim($file[$j]))` does not work because it is trying to split on 'backslash and t' (two separate characters after each other) (= `'\t'`). For it to work, it needs to split on the tab character (= `"\t"`). The difference is that single quotes are 'dumb', i.e. they see `\t` as the two separate characters, while double quotes are 'smart', i.e. they see `\t` as the single character 'tab'.

`preg_split($separator)` does not work because it requires some delimiters to the pattern, like `/`. This is true even when splitting on something simple, like `'a'`.

For this particular problem, `explode()` is the more appropriate solution (simpler and slightly faster). If you change the character in `$rows['separator']` to `"\t"` (wherever that value is fetched from), `explode()` should work.

Comment: Using your answer and the other one I tried to delimit the `$rows['separator']` such as `$line = explode('/'.$rows['separator'].'/', trim($file[$j]));`

However I got nothing from it. $rows in generated from a query and the `\t` is written in the table like that, if I change it in the code, I can't seem to get a way to do it instead of hard coding each case. For instance:
    if('\t')
        $rows = "\t"
    else if('\n')
         $rows = "\n"

Comment: `preg_split()` requires the delimiters (like `/`); `explode()` does not. The table then contains two characters (backslash and the letter t) while the actual separator is one character (tab). Unfortunately, it is not easy to convert the two characters (backslash and the letter t) to the character (tab) they represent. Ideally, this would be corrected in the database table. If that's not possible, you can either use `preg_split()` after all or run a replace function first: `$rows['separator'] = str_replace('\t', "\t", $rows['separator']);`.

Comment: For now I think I'll use the `preg_split`, but since `explode()` is lihgter, I'll look into changing the table (I've tried to put `"\t"` directly in the table). I'll try using the ascii code for `\t` and then exploding.